# Is it possible to turn into a werewolf with the 'Ring of Hircine' after curing the werewolf status?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to be a werewolf, and I also want to a vampire. If I cure my Werewolf ability, will I still be able to change into a werewolf using my *Ring of Hircine*.

Answer (score 3):

No, the [Ring of Hircine](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Hircine's_Ring_(Skyrim)) allows for one additional transformation per day, but only if you are already a werewolf.  If you cure yourself you will never be able to become a werewolf again, and also you may run into a bug that prevents you from becoming a vampire.